# A farmer wants to build sheep pen.

Tags: derivatives

A farmer wish to build rectangular sheep pen with $200\ m$ fence, using one side of an existing shed as the side. The shed is square  of measurement $30\ m \times 30\ m$.

1) Find the measurement and the area of the sheep pen if one side of  the existing shed is used as the width of the sheep pen.

2) By using the fence of the same length and using the width of the shed as PART of the width of the sheep pen, find the length and width of the sheep pen with maximum area.

For question 1, I got the $width = 30\ m$. So, the *length* is $85\ m$. ($85+85+30=200$, one side of existing shed made the other width of the sheep pen)

For question 2, the maximum area would be square $(57.5 \times 57.5)$ But, in this question, it want us to build a rectangular sheep pen. So, I change the length to $57.51$ and the width $57.49$ to make it rectangular in shape.

ARE MY ANSWERS CORRECT?

(https://www.google.com/search?q=sheep+pen&client=ms-android-asus&hl=en-GB&biw=360&bih=555&prmd=isnv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixpeTG_NzRAhWMpJQKHcogD0sQ_AUIBygB#imgrc=x7XZ_IMn_GlgBM%3A)

Comment: A square is a rectangle.

Comment: The same way a Fanta is still a beverage, a square is still a rectangle. Besides, why did you settle for $57.49\times 57.51$ when $57.499 \times 57.501$ is larger?